# Trouble adding total value while converting string to int

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select fields that ask the user two different questions and adds the overall value to the final total depending on the selected value. I'm not fully understanding why the final total is saying $NaN USD when I select the second select field first but if I select the first select field first then it doesn't display $NaN USD.

```js
var total;

$('.form-contro').on('change', function() {
  var get = $('#form-contro option:selected').val();
  total = Number(get);

  $('.text-center h2 span').html(total + " USD");
});


$('.form-contr').on('change', function() {
  var get = $('#form-contr option:selected').val();

  if (get === 'no') {
    total = 1000;
  } else if (get === 'yes') {
    total = total + 30;
  }

  $('.text-center h2 span').html(total + " USD");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 12px; color: #888; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;" for="states">Number of items:</label>
<select class="form-contro" id="form-contro" style="width: 320px; height: 40px; text-indent: 10px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 4px; border-style: solid; border-color: #343434;">
     <option value="90" id="items">1 Item</option>
     <option value="95.50" id="items">2 Items</option>
     <option value="100" id="items">3 Items</option>
     <option value="105" id="items">4 Item</option>
</select>

<label class="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 12px; color: #888; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;" for="states">Will you be flying?</label>
<select class="form-contr" id="form-contr" style="width: 320px; height: 40px; text-indent: 10px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 4px; border-style: solid; border-color: #343434;">
     <option value="no" id="items">No</option>
     <option value="yes" id="items">Yes</option>
</select>

<div class="text-center" style="clear: both;">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 40px;">Total amount $<span id="new_text">90 USD</span></h2>
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to Javascript so any help is appreciated since I've been working on this problem awhile.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to add the two select values together without getting the $NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give total an initial value, so at the top, make the value of total:
`var total = 0;`

The reason you don't get NaN the other way around, is because you used `Number(get)`, which gives it a default value of 0 if null.

Comment: Wow, that was super easy.. Thanks!